# Prior predictive with discrete prior

Tags: bayesian, prior

I'm working with a uniform distribution as a prior, defined as:

$\pi(\theta) =
  \begin{cases}
   \frac{1}{7} & \text{if } \theta\in\{0,\frac{1}{6},\frac{2}{6},\ldots,1\} \\
   0       & \text{otherwise }
  \end{cases}$

I've to compute the prior predictive, but I don't know how to deal with this discrete distribution. With a continuous one, I'd compute as,

$P(\tilde{y})=\int_{\Omega}P(y|\theta)\pi(\theta)d\theta$

I know how to deal with this integral with a continuous distribution, but not with a uniform. As a model I'm using a $P(y|\theta)=Bin(20,\theta)$

I guess I've to do something with a sum $\sum$, but I'm not proficient in maths. 
Thank you in advance!

Kenneth.

Comment: yes the integral just becomes a sum

Comment: Glen_b is correct - in the discrete case, the integral becomes a sum over the support of the distribution. This is discussed in the first chapter of Gelman's Bayesian Data Analysis.

Answer (score 2):

The integral becomes a sum over the possible values of $\theta$.